# R mschart dashed line for line chart

Tags: r, mschart

Is it possible to make dashed lines for a line chart created using `ms_linechart`?

I see that you can use `chart_data_fill`, `chart_data_stroke`, `chart_data_symbol`, `chart_data_size`, `chart_data_line_width` to modify the fill, stroke, symbol, size, line width respectfully. However, there does not appear to be a function like: `chart_data_dash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with pull request [#59](https://github.com/ardata-fr/mschart/pull/59)